# Making posts and storing them using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I was given a suggestion for my web app as follows:

> You'll want to do an AJAX POST with the text and the annotation position to save the data on the server, so you'll to have a URL in your app that can accept those.

Basically, I have a JS script running that gets selected text on the page and posts it into a particular div. I want, however, to get that text to store in my database, if I could.

How do I go about doing that? I was recently going through this one: [How to Make a Feed From User Submitted Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533051/how-to-make-a-feed-from-user-submitted-posts) ...

It didn't quite get me where I wanted, though. For good measure, here is the JS script I am using to get the selected text off the page.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        function getSelText()
    {
    var txt = '';
    var foundIn = '';
        if (window.getSelection)
        { 
        txt = window.getSelection();


    }
        else if (document.getSelection)
        {
        txt = document.getSelection();

    }
        else if (document.selection)
        {   
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;

    }
        else return;
        document.aform.selectedtext.value =  txt;
    }
    // -->
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the suggestion has mentioned earlier, you'd need to do an AJAX post to the server where your serverside script is running. Your server side script shall have a url, for example: `http://www.example.com/saveselection.php`. You can read up about ajax [post in basic javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289294/ajax-post-and-php) or in [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). You should know some server scripting to save the selected posted in your preferred language.

Comment: Thanks, Mike, I'll continue to do some research.